# For which tables of user A do a user B have INSERT rights?

Tags: oracle, function, permissions, roles

I'm trying to create a function with the following signature:

`FUNCTION tableList(user_a VARCHAR2, user_b VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2;`

Which would print a list of `table`s as comma separated string, **where** each `table`'s owner is `user_a` **and** `user_b` has `INSERT` rights for it.

I've found out that this is not a trivial answer, since one could `GRANT role_1 TO role_2` as well as `GRANT role_2 TO user_x`, so these connections build up a tree. I have also found out, that `dba_tab_privs` stores tables with their owner and grantee. It gets tricky, when the `grantee` column stores a `ROLE`.

I'm looking for the function at hand.

Comment: Once you start looking at roles, things get potentially complicated depending on how complete the solution needs to be.  What if the user has a non-default role that has access to the table?  The user wouldn't be able to access the table after logging in but could enable an additional role that did allow that.  What if the user has a password-protected role that has access to the table?  Do you want to account for things like users with the `SELECT ANY TABLE` privilege as well?  What is the underlying problem that you're trying to solve-- there may be other approaches.

Comment: The solution needs to be complete, as:
It has to retrieve **every** table (with **owner** `user_a`) which the `user_b` could `INSERT` into, using the `INSERT INTO` clause.

Comment: OK.  How do you want to handle non-default roles?  Password-protected roles?  How do you want to handle the fact that roles can be enabled nd disabled on a per-session basis?  And what is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: There is no underlying problem, I just simply play with Oracle roles. I would like to query permissions for the current state of a session, so if the `user_b` is currently logged in and activated a password-protected role, which allow him/her to `INSERT` into a specific table of `user_a`, so it should be listed, otherwise not. I can't realize how this would change the solution.

Comment: What if `user_b` is not logged in?  What if `user_b` has three sessions, one with all roles disabled, one with default roles enabled, and one with the default roles and one password-protected role?  In general, this gets rather complicated rather quickly if you want a complete solution that covers ever possible case.

Comment: Could you show me a simple solution that excludes these session-dependent roles? And on another example: how would these information complicate it? As you see, my knowledge is very limited on this matter, so that's the case why I can't answer your intermediate questions.

Comment: All roles are session-dependent.  Are you asking for a simple solution excluding roles?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41796/discussion-between-dyin-and-justin-cave)